# Use same Styling files (.SCSS) for multiple angular 8 projects

Tags: angular, sass, angular-library

I Have different projects developed in angular 8 and have same styling.

I want to use same `SCSS` files so that in future changes can be made at one place.

I have tried below but this is not working for me.

[Compiling css in new Angular 6 libraries](https://medium.com/@Dor3nz/compiling-css-in-new-angular-6-libraries-26f80274d8e5)

Please guide to right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can:

1. Create your `npm` or `yarn` package (it can be private) with styles.
2. Use it as a `package.json` dependency to a different projects
3. Profit )

Useful links:

https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages

https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-an-org-scoped-package

Other option can be:

1. create single angular project with one `package.json` and `angular.json`
2. have different project in different folders
3. have common styles inserted in every project
4. have different commands in `package.json` to run different projects (on different ports if you need it to run at the same time)
5. have different configurations in `angular.json` for different projects

Comment: Can I ask for  some link that can help me to use styles from library ?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved with the help of @qiAlex's answer , but here I am posting complete procedure to resolve these kind of issues.

I got below solution from https://github.com/linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr.

These kind of problems can be resolved through creating an angular library but the default angular build architect **@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr** for ng-packagr doesn't copy assets of libraries.

**@linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr** can be used to copy assets of library. This Angular Build Architect will copy all assets in library build.

### How to install

Install **@linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr** into your angular project.

npm install @linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr --save-dev

or

yarn add @linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr --dev

### How to use

I). Replace the build architect of your libraries by @linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr:build.

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr:build",
```

II). Add your assets glob rules to the options section like as you normally do for apps.

```
 "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/weave-styles/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/weave-styles/ng-package.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
```

A final angular.json file could look like the following example:

```
"weave-styles": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/weave-styles",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/weave-styles/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@linnenschmidt/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/weave-styles/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/weave-styles/ng-package.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/weave-styles/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/weave-styles/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/weave-styles/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/weave-styles/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/weave-styles/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
```